# Locate tool won’t work, how do I fix

Tags: terminal, macos

I was trying to update the locate database, but when input `sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb`, I got a bunch of errors. When I try to use locate again it would not work. I can’t remember what I did, but I ended up finding out that the `locate.updatedb` file had been corrupted. I got locate to work again by using Time Machine to recover the locate.database file. But I want to be able to update locate without corrupting the file. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open Terminal.app and run the following two commands:

```
cd /
sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb
```

The "cd /" part is important as you need to be in a path where the user "nobody" has permissions.

Comment: Was not running the command in the “/“ directory what most likely corrupted the file?

Comment: It shouldn't have corrupted the file, no.

Answer (score 4):

The command to update the database is

```
sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb
```

It should get run automatically every week from `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist` but you can run it manually if required.

Comment: Sorry. That was my fault, I actually put into the terminal “/usr/libexec/locate.updatedb”. I guess I was thinking about where the locate database was when I was writing the question. I changed that part of my question.

Comment: And that is nice to know that it updates everyday, thank you.

Comment: Is there a way to run this so it is actually synced. Meaning if I delete then things get removed. Also if add, things get added to the index?

Comment: @momo you can use `mdfind` which uses the Spotlight index. Updating the db `locate` always requires a full filesystem scan, that‘s not something you want to run every few minutes.