# Can't update locate db

Tags: catalina, permission

When I run `sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb` I get this:

```
mktemp: too few X's in template ‘updatedb’
chown: missing operand after ‘nobody’
Try 'chown --help' for more information.
rmdir: /tmp/locatepZ6k0NJsdA/mklocatedcjJiipxrq: No such file or directory
rmdir: /tmp/locatepZ6k0NJsdA: No such file or directory
install: missing destination file operand after '/var/db/locate.database'
Try 'install --help' for more information.
rm: missing operand
Try 'rm --help' for more information.
```

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/301368/locate-tool-won-t-work-how-do-i-fix - will this help ?

Comment: Same errors when following the accepted answer.